# Resolve npm cache folder issue inside Docker container only happened on ubuntu 22.04 host OS but not on macOS

Tags: docker, ubuntu, npm

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy-20220801

# this is needed to run parallelism in tests
# because openpyxl during parallel tests can cause bad number
# so the only solution is to avoid write .pyc during tests
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update

# needed for universe repository
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python3.10-venv

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv

RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# this is needed for the adding of ppa apt-add-repository
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata

# needed for pip3
RUN add-apt-repository universe

# cause everytime add apt-reposutory need to update to work
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install git  -y

RUN apt-get install vim -y

RUN pip install --upgrade pip==22.0.4

#########################################
#
# Tailwind needs
#   node and npm
#     and node needs curl
#########################################

RUN apt-get update

# to install node
RUN apt-get install -y curl

# for getting latest version
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash

RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    # for tailwind and no need to install npm cause node now comes with it prepackaged
    nodejs

# RUN npm install -g npm@8.5.5
RUN npm install -g npm@8.15.1

RUN chown -R 1000:1000 "/root/.npm"

# End of Tailwind requirement

# for other standard libraries
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    # psycopg2 dependencies
    libpq-dev gcc python3-dev

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get -y clean

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install pip-tools
RUN pip-sync /requirements/base.txt /requirements/production.txt

COPY . /code/

COPY ./compose/production/tech/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
COPY ./compose/production/tech/django/ /

#########################################
#
# For the smallest possible style.css, Tailwind needs to
#   run install node_modules at /code/theme/static_src
#   and run npm audit fix at /code/theme/static_src
#########################################

RUN /usr/bin/npm cache clean --force && cd /code/theme/static_src && /usr/bin/npm install

RUN for n in entrypoint start-*; do \
    sed -i 's/\r//' /$n; \
    chmod +x /$n; \
    done

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint"]


# End of Tailwind

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

production.yml

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  reverse_proxy:
    name: djangogreen_reverse_proxy
  backend:

volumes:
  production_nginx_iconf_d:
  production_nginx_vhost_d:
  production_nginx_html:
  production_nginx_certs:
  # postgres_data_production:
  # postgres_backup_production:
  pg14_postgres_data_production:
  pg14_postgres_backup_production:
  # node_modules_volume:

services:
  nginx:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build: ./compose/production/tech/nginx/
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - ./media/:/django/media/:ro
      - ./static/:/django/static/:ro
      - ./compose/production/tech/nginx/default-external.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./compose/production/tech/nginx/ssl.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf
      - ./compose/production/tech/nginx/certs/greendeployhq.com/:/etc/cloudflare/live/greendeployhq.com/:ro
      - ./compose/production/tech/nginx/certs/greendeploy.io/:/etc/cloudflare/live/greendeploy.io/:ro
    networks:
      - reverse_proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

  django:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/platform/doap/Dockerfile
    image: django-green_production_django
    depends_on:
      # - mailhog
      - redis
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./staticfiles/:/code/staticfiles/
      - ./static/:/code/static/
      - ./media/:/code/media/
      # - node_modules_volume:/code/theme/static_src/node_modules/
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
      - ./.envs/.local/.github
    networks:
      - reverse_proxy
      - backend
    expose:
      - "5000"
    command: gunicorn composeexample.wsgi --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout 120 --workers=3 --threads=3 --worker-connections=1000

  postgres:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build: ./compose/production/tech/postgres/
    image: django-green_production_postgres
    container_name: postgres
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - pg14_postgres_data_production:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - pg14_postgres_backup_production:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  # mailhog:
  #   image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
  #   ports:
  #     - "8025:8025"

  redis:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build: ./compose/production/tech/redis/
    container_name: redis
    # need to make sure redis on same network else wont work
    # with django using redis://redis:6379/0 as REDIS_URL
    networks:
      - reverse_proxy
      - backend
    restart: always

  huey:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/platform/doap/Dockerfile
    command: /start-hueyworker
    networks:
      - reverse_proxy
      - backend
    volumes:
      - .:/code/
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    depends_on:
      - django
      - postgres
      - redis
```

I run the following commands

- `docker-compose -f production.yml build`
- `docker-compose -f production.yml run --rm django python3 manage.py tailwind update`
- `docker-compose -f production.yml run --rm django python3 manage.py tailwind build`

The second command

```
up to date, audited 101 packages in 12s

20 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

The third command :

```
> theme@3.1.1 build
> npm run build:clean && npm run build:tailwind

npm WARN logfile Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'
npm WARN logfile  error cleaning log files [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
npm WARN logfile   errno: -13,
npm WARN logfile   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN logfile   syscall: 'scandir',
npm WARN logfile   path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
npm WARN logfile }
(⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠏ : WARN logfile Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'
> theme@3.1.1 build:clean
> rimraf ../static/css/dist

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/root/.npm"

npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: /root/.npm/_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal
```

How do I fix this issue? I have no issue with running the exact command on my localhost macOS and I cannot replicate this. BUt when I run on ubuntu 22.04 VPS, then I get the above issue. I even tried on a different host, and the same thing happened.

### update

on the server

```
ubuntu@greenland-private:~/code/private-django-green$ sudo docker-compose -f production.yml run --rm django id
Creating private-django-green_django_run ... done
Going to use psycopg2 to connect to postgres
psycopg2 successfully connected to postgres
PostgreSQL is available
Going to use redis-py to connect to redis
redis successfully connected
Redis is available
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

on the mac

```
Going to use psycopg2 to connect to postgres
psycopg2 successfully connected to postgres
PostgreSQL is available
Going to use redis-py to connect to redis
redis successfully connected
Redis is available
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

on the entrypoint file

```
#!/bin/sh

set -o errexit
# must comment out pipefail for debian-based images
# set -o pipefail
set -o nounset


# N.B. If only .env files supported variable expansion...
# export CELERY_BROKER_URL="${REDIS_URL}"

if [ -z "${POSTGRES_USER}" ]; then
    base_postgres_image_default_user='postgres'
    export POSTGRES_USER="${base_postgres_image_default_user}"
fi
export DATABASE_URL="postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}"

postgres_ready() {
python3 << END
import sys

import psycopg2

try:
    print("Going to use psycopg2 to connect to postgres")
    psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="${POSTGRES_DB}",
        user="${POSTGRES_USER}",
        password="${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}",
        host="${POSTGRES_HOST}",
        port="${POSTGRES_PORT}",
    )
    print("psycopg2 successfully connected to postgres")
except psycopg2.OperationalError:
    print("Op error: {0}".format(err))
    sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(0)

END
}
until postgres_ready; do
  >&2 echo 'Waiting for PostgreSQL to become available...'
  sleep 1
done
>&2 echo 'PostgreSQL is available'

redis_ready() {
python3 << END
import sys
import redis
try:
    print("Going to use redis-py to connect to redis")
    r = redis.Redis(host="${REDIS_HOST}", port="${REDIS_PORT}")
    if r.ping():
        print("redis successfully connected")
        sys.exit(0)
    sys.exit(-1)
except OSError as err:
    print("Op error: {0}".format(err))
    sys.exit(-1)

END
}
until redis_ready; do
  >&2 echo 'Waiting for Redis to become available...'
  sleep 1
done
>&2 echo 'Redis is available'

exec "$@"
```

### Workaround

in the Dockerfile, i need to change this line

```
RUN npm install -g npm@8.15.1
```

to

```
RUN npm install -g npm@8.14.0
```

I am not sure why this works.

Comment: Is there something in this setup that creates and switches to a non-root user?  I don't see that in the listing; I'd expect this command to run as root and so not have permission issues.  (Can you run this build sequence in your Dockerfile instead of doing it manually after the image is built?  Can you get rid of all of the `volumes:` that inject things into the container and keep the image self-contained?)

Comment: Sorry im not very versed with docker so i dont understand your suggestion. I need the volumes. And I do want to repeat that the exact same docker file and yml I had no issue running in macOS.

Comment: If you `docker-compose -f production.yaml run --rm django id`, who are you?  What is in the `entrypoint` script?

Comment: @DavidMaze answered in the updated question

Comment: I solved it by downgrading the npm to 8.14.0 I don't know why that works